# Polish Character encoding issue in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am getting issue for polish characters in ajax call. In alert shown in below code, polish characters are not coming properly.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/module/getAllApps.htm",
        encoding:"UTF-8",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        async: true,
        success : function(response) { 
            if(response != null && response != "" && response!= '' && response != 'null'){
                var appList = JSON.parse(response);
                for(var i=0; i<appList.length; i++){
                    var module = appList[i];
                    alert(module.title);
                 }
              }
        },
        error : function(e){
            console.log('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
```

Below is method from Controller class

```
public void getAllApps(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Module> moduleList = moduleDao.getAllActiveModulesByDomain(domain.getDomainId());

    try {
        if(moduleList != null && moduleList.size()> 0){
            response.getWriter().print(gson.toJson(moduleList));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How aren't they coming properly? Be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you're using the *CharacterEncodingFilter*, add the following in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can also make sure that your server is configured properly, for tomcat for instance adding URIEncoding to connector

```
<connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

will specify the character encoding used to decode the URI. You should find an equivalent for your server

Finally, if you're problem persists, check that the decoding of your DB and your connection to the DB is also properly set

Comment: did you cover first two points, there's also an encoding setup on the connection string for mysql an exemplary connection string, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_Name?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8 with this four points covered your encoding should be proper