# Character-encoding Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, character-encoding, turkish

I am having trouble with Turkish characters...In my JSP pages, there is no problem... but, when an alert come from Java side, Turkish character(ŞşİığĞüÜç...) seems like that (Ä±,?,Ã¼,Ã§,Å,...)

In JSP pages, I use this code and ı can solve Turkish character problem

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
```

in Spring MVC config, I tried  a lot of way but I didn't succeed... For example In my mvc config class, I set my MessageSource like that;

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

In this program, I try to reset password and I typed unregister email address..Finally I am getting exception and this following is exception code blog.

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messages;
...

@ExceptionHandler({ UserNotFoundException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNotFound(final RuntimeException exception, final WebRequest request) {
    logger.error("404 Status Code", exception);
    final GenericResponse bodyOfResponse = new GenericResponse(messages.getMessage("message.userNotFound", null, request.getLocale()), "UserNotFound");
    return handleExceptionInternal(exception, bodyOfResponse, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
}
```

In my messages_tr_TR.properties file,

```
...
message.userNotFound=Kullanıcı Bulunamadı
...
```

but In JSP pages this alert shows like that;

**KullanÄ±cÄ± BulunamadÄ±**

How can I solve this problem..

Comment: With encoding there are several common causes, you can try adding the filter and configuring your servlet container as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831145/polish-character-encoding-issue-in-ajax-call/28831361#28831361). [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) you can find a comprehensive  list of common issues, check the point number two if the first link doesn't help

Comment: Hi @MasterSlave ,thanks for comment. I've tried second link before...In first link, there are a lot of ways but I am looking for Spring MVC one...How can I solve this issue in Spring MVC

Comment: I've added an answer simply on account of formatting, but in reality its only yet another suggestion, let me know if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Comment follow-up, you can set the encoding in your response header as well. An example if you're returning `json` would be

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
return handleExceptionInternal(exception, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :( I am getting same result.

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml:

```
<jsp-config>
    <!-- global JSP configuration -->
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>

<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Put the actual text in the handler method (temporarily). Does it now look right? Is your messages file correctly saved as UTF-8? Also, I can't tell if you're using JSON or not...

Comment: thanks for answer but it didn't work...when I add this to the web.xml, it effects only some information messages...I mean, there is no neccessary to use this code blog in jsp pages anymore     <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>     .... As I understand **message.userNotFound=Kullanıcı Bulunamadı** message use different way... I am having trouble only some information messages not all of them.

Comment: By the way, I didn't understand very well "Is your messages file correctly saved as UTF-8?" what did you mean???